# Pegar o objeto da lista ou fazer um novo select no banco?

Tags: java, jee

Tenho um Controller que a primeira coisa que ele faz, é trazer do banco uma lista de objetos. Após clicar num dos botões, o cliente vai usar um dos itens da lista.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Qual seria a melhor forma de pegar esse objeto? Dá lista que já tenho, ou faço um novo select no banco?

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        int IdPaciente = Integer.parseInt(Str.NullToStrDef(FaceUtil.getRequest().getParameter("idpaciente"), "0"));
        paciente = pacienteDao.find(IdPaciente);
        listProgramas = programaDao.findByAplicador(loginController.getUsuarioLogado().getIdusuario(), IdPaciente);
        
        int IdPrograma = Integer.parseInt(Str.NullToStrDef(FaceUtil.getRequest().getParameter("programa"), "0"));
        if(IdPrograma > 0) {

            programaAplicando = programaDao.find(IdPrograma); //Assim?
            
            programaAplicando = listProgramas.stream()
                    .filter(t -> t.getIdprograma() == IdPrograma)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0); //ou assim?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandre Biancuzzi,
É um pouco difícil sugerir algo, pois não tenho todo o conhecimento do seu código e de suas implementações e nem sua real necessidade.

Segue abaixo minhas contribuições, talvez ajude em algo:

#### 1 Validações antes de consumir o banco de dados

O custo do Banco de dados é altíssimo ( Integridade da base, valor dos dados, valor da concorrencias das conexões, valor em R$ kkkk, comparação de escalanomento de aplicação x escalonamento do banco e etc ).

O máximo que for possível fazer validações de negócios, validações dos parametros do requests, preparações de variáveis antes de consumir o banco será melhor.

#### 2 Trazer os dados atualizados ao usuário

Não entendi o que o seu controller faz. Mais é inevitável o ato de sempre tentar trazer o dado mais atualizado ao usuário.

Ou seja será necessário sempre ir ao banco trazer a informação mais atualizada ( ou utilizar outras tecnicas como caches e proxies ), mais creio eu que não é uma boa prática buscar uma lista em algum momento sem novamente ir no banco e atualizá-la conforme o que está no banco. Teoricamente na maioria dos casos o usuário irá querer esta informação atualizada em cada request ( dependendo da regra de negócio é claro ).

#### 3 Otimize suas buscas nos bancos.

O máximo que for possível fazer o menor número de buscas no banco e o máximo de buscas otimizadas melhor será para o trafego das informações, otimizações no processamento do banco e diminuicão da concorrência de conexões ao banco.

Referente ao seu código, seria melhor se vc tivesse algo em seu `DAO` que não precisasse trazer toda a lista de programas para a aplicação sendo que irá usar apenas o primeiro item ex:

```java
    programaAplicando = programaDao.findOnlyOneObjectByIdPacienteAndIdPrograma(
                             Integer.parseInt(Str.NullToStrDef(FaceUtil.getRequest().getParameter("idpaciente"), "0"),
                             Str.NullToStrDef(FaceUtil.getRequest().getParameter("programa"), "0")
                        );
```

Comment: Legal Dilermando! Era +- o que tinha em mente mesmo, mas precisava saber se fazia "sentido". Uma das coisas que me preocupo sempre, é não fazer requisições ao banco desnecessariamente. Referente à sua sugestão, realmente preciso trazer todos os programas, já que o usuário irá "pegar" um deles para executar. E como uso um ViewScoped, não preciso dar outro select. No caso, o programa não é alterado com frequência, portanto, não preciso me preocupar com concorrência de dados. ;o)